# How to dynamically update a SwiftUI View with an @Bindable value

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a SwiftUI `ProgressBar` View that displays the percentage progress based on a percentage-value you enter as a Bindable parameter. The progress percentage-value is calculated by a `ReminderHelper` class, which takes two Ints as its parameters, `totalDays` and `daysLeft`, the values input to the ReminderHelper class come from a `Reminder` object saved in Core Data.

I'm very confused as to how to structure my code to accomplish such of thing due to the poor understanding of how the SwiftUI/Combine, @Binding, @Published, @State, etc. work.

Based on the code below, what I'm expecting to see is two reminders, `Cut the Grass` at 20% and `Power Wash Siding` at 50%.  Again, the two `Ints` that determine the total percentage progress come from the `Reminder` object saved in Core Data and the actual total percentage result comes from the `RemindersHelper` class.

Any idea how to accomplish what I describe above?

### Model:

This is saved in Core Data.

```
class Reminder: Identifiable {
    var name = ""
    var totalDays = 0
    var daysLeft = 0
    
    init(name: String, totalDays: Int, daysLeft: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.totalDays = totalDays
        self.daysLeft = daysLeft
    }
}
```

### Helper class

This needs to be in charge of calculating the total percentage that will be passed to the ProgressBar View with the values coming
from the Reminder object saved in Core Data.

```
class ReminderHelper: ObservableObject {
    @Published var percentageLeft: Float = 0.80
    
    func calculatePercentageLeft(daysLeft: Int, totalDays: Int) -> Float {
        percentageLeft  = Float(daysLeft / totalDays)
        return percentageLeft
    }
}
```

### Content View:

Here I'm calling the `calculatePercentageLeft` method to prepare the `percentageLeft` property before presenting the ProgressBar. Which of course is not working.
I see an error:

> Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Float' conform to 'View'

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var reminders = [Reminder(name: "Cut the Grass", totalDays: 50, daysLeft: 10),
                Reminder(name: "Power Wash Siding", totalDays: 30, daysLeft: 15)]
    
    @StateObject var reminderModel = ReminderHelper()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(reminders) { reminder in
                HStack {
                    Text(reminder.name)
                    reminderModel.calculatePercentageLeft(daysLeft: reminder.daysLeft, totalDays: reminder.totalDays)
                    ProgressBar(progress: reminderModel.percentageLeft)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### ProgressBar View

This is the view in charge of drawing and displaying the percentage value.

```
struct ProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var progress: Float
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                .opacity(0.3)
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(self.progress, 1.0)))
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
                .animation(.linear, value: progress)

            VStack {
                Text(String(format: "%.0f %%", min(self.progress, 1.0) * 100.0))
                    .font(.caption2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears because your function returns a Float and every function that gets called in a buildblock like HStack should return a view.

You should change the design of your Model to acomplish what you want.

Create a calculated var in your Model (this won´t affect Coredata).

```
class Reminder:Identifiable{
    var name = ""
    var totalDays = 0
    var daysLeft = 0
    
    var percentageLeft: Float {
        Float(daysLeft) / Float(totalDays)
    }
    
    init(name:String, totalDays:Int, daysLeft:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.totalDays = totalDays
        self.daysLeft = daysLeft
    }
}
```

Then use this var to display the progress:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var reminders = [Reminder(name: "Cut the Grass", totalDays: 50, daysLeft: 10),
                Reminder(name: "Power Wash Siding", totalDays: 30, daysLeft: 15)]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(reminders) { reminder in
                HStack{
                    Text(reminder.name)
                    ProgressBar(progress: reminder.percentageLeft)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Aditional changes:

- Depending on your overall design you may not need the Viewmodel here anymore.
- I changed `Float(daysLeft / totalDays)` to `Float(dayLeft) / Float(totalDays)` as the first will allways produce 0
- I changed `@Bining var progress: Float` to `var progress: Float`. You do not need a binding here. You only need one if the value of progress gets changed inside `ProgressView` and needs to get propagated to the parent `ContentView`

Comment: @ burnsi -  Your answer led me to the right answer, I removed all Binding related, changed the `Float(daysLeft / totalDays)` to `Float(dayLeft) / Float(totalDays)` and just called the `calculatePercentageLeft` function directly from the `ProgressBar` view.  Quick question, can you add a computed property to a model managed by Core Data without an extension?  Again, Reminder is a Core Data object which contains daysLeft and totalDays as attributes. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `can you add a computed property to a model managed by Core Data without an extension?` - Yes, thats why i stated `(this won´t affect Coredata)`. And something like a percentage value should live in the model.

Comment: @fs_tigre Moving the Helperclass to your ProgressView would help. But it seems a bad design.

Comment: Oh, no I didn't move the code from the Helper class to the ProgressBar view, I just passed it as an argument to the view as follow... `ProgressBar(progress: reminderHelper.calculatePerentageLeft(daysLeft: reminder.daysLeft, totalDays: reminder.totalDays))`.  I'll see if I can incorporate this method into the `ReminderViewModel`, which is the class in charge of managing the `Reminder` object from Core Data. FYI - I'm using MVVM to manange my Core Data + SwiftUI.  Thanks a lot for your help.